# Printing logcat entries with highlighting

Tags: android, logcat

I'm developing an Android application and need to include error messages I encountered / resolved in the documentation.

Is there a method to print logcat output as they appear in the logcat window with the highlighting, I can save the output but it is saved to a raw text file

Any suggestions short of print screening the console ?

Thanks

Comment: What operating system are you using? Also, are you using logcat from an IDE (such as Eclipse) or directly from the command line?

Comment: Windows 7, Logcat from inside Eclipse which is why I thought print screening would be a fall back if there isn't a suitable method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a script to convert the plain text into HTML with your desired styling would seem to be fairly easy.

Comment: Interesting idea. I was hoping for an existing solution but I suppose I could script one.

Comment: Googlize for coloredlogcat. That could be a good start since it should not be too difficult to replace console tag by some html formatting